# button click causes form validation in two forms

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick

I have two buttons in one form i.e sign-in and signup.Whenever i click any of the button it causes validation check in both forms.How do solve this problem.???The page containing both button is a user-control file. ***Please HELP!!!!***

```
<asp:Button ID="login_btn"  runat="server" Height="32px" 
Text="Login" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" 
Width="82px" onclick="login_btn_Click" />
<br />
```

And when i add causesvalidation="false" it solves the problem i.e dosen't check validation for both forms.BUT what troubles is that it now doesn't even check the validation of the form triggered by the button click. What exactly do the causevalidation do? and how do i solve the problem mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group each control in the form using [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, then spesify the `ValidationGroup` in the button control.

```
<asp:Button ID="login_btn"  runat="server" Height="32px" 
Text="Login" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" 
Width="82px" onclick="login_btn_Click" ValidationGroup="group1"/>
<br />

<asp:Button ID="signin_btn"  runat="server" Height="32px" 
Text="Sign Up" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" 
Width="82px" onclick="signin_btn_Click" ValidationGroup="group2"/>
<br />
```

More example and explanation: see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It worked.I realized,We need to specify the group of field we are trying to validate in the specific button click using group validation.